# Calculate the KL divergence between two transition matrices

Tags: st.statistics, markov-chains, entropy

I want to calculate how different two markov transition matrices are.

For example:

$\begin{pmatrix} .2 & .8 \\ .1 & .9 \end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix} .3 & .7 \\ .1 & .9 \end{pmatrix}$

Could I use KL (Kullback-Leibler) divergence or is there some assumption I need to check. (Reading [this](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/%7Eweb/Papers/rac-it-div04.ps) confused me). Using the euclidean distance between the two would give me what I want. Is KL a better measure?

Comment: Each row in a transition matrix is a conditional distribution. So you could find individual kl distances between the rows, but the matrix is then a collection of distributions and it does not make sense to take kl distance of a set of distributions

Comment: What if I would simply add the kl distance of each set. Would that give me an indication of how far from each other they are? I have a feeling Euclidean distance might work better

Comment: The problem with just adding is that you can define any kind of metric between two sets. You could take a min, average distance, Earthmover distance or whatever. Which one is optimal? Who knows? If you want to stick to KL divergence then what you really want to do is compute an expectation of log(P/Q) where both P and Q should be distributions. So one thing you might do is to find the stationary distribution over the rows and then compute a full joint probability over both the rows and columns and then compute the KL between the two joint distributions.

Comment: You could take a look at the Kullback-Leibler divergence rate between Markov chains; there is a paper in the Transactions on Information Theory by Rached et al.